# Retrieving a single column or two columns in android studio from sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";
    public static final String COL_5 = "DATETIMEZ";

public Cursor NAME_MARKS() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
```

//does not work

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select COL_2,COL_3 from " + TABLE_NAME, null);{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col_2` and `col_3` are the names of the **variables**, not the columns in the database. If you want to use them, you'll need to use some sort of string manipulation/concatination. E.g.:

```
Cursor res = 
    db.rawQuery("select " + COL_2 + ", " + COL_3 + " from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
```

Comment: my app crashes unfortunately stopped